# Dealing with fragmenttransaction when using FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment-tab-host, fragmenttransaction

so heres the issues,

i'm using fragmenttabhost with four tab, Tab A(FragA), Tab B(FragB), Tab C, Tab D

when i using Tab B, and i do a fragment transaction to replace the fragment on Tab B(FragB) to another fragment(FragB_2), it is added to the back stack, so i can still navigate back by using the back button. but when at Tab B new fragment, i click on Tab A, Tab C, Tab D. then when i go back to Tab B, the tab will be displaying the new fragment(FragB_2), and when i press on the back button.. no fragment is display.

i had try to remove the backstack whenever i do tab change. etc

```
if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) 
{
    Log.i("MainActivity", "popping backstack");

        fm.popBackStack();
}
```

this code remove the Fragment B_2 from the TabB, but whenever i go back to Tab B again, Fragment B is gone.

how to i go around it?

Comment: So you want when you are on one tab and go to another then on backpress its not go back to previous activity?

Comment: when i on Tab B, i had a fragment transaction to replace the fragment(Frag A) to another fragment(Frag B). then when i go to Tab A, then i go back to Tab B again, the fragment is still Frag B, i want it to be the Frag A.

Comment: check this- http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/